# How to select column name with special character for dynamic pivot - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble selecting a column with "<" in column name from a SQL table.

This is for SQL Server Management Server 2012.

When I select columns using the following code, I get a list of columns. One of the columns has a special character in it "<". The value of the column is "< 2004".

```
select NAME
from sys.columns
where object_id=OBJECT_ID('[table_name]')
and (NAME LIKE '2%' or NAME LIKE '< 2%')
```

[image: columns from table]

But when I use this code for the dynamic pivot, it gives me an error that says:

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7

Invalid column name '< 2004'.

Edit: Adding an image of the error:
[image: error]

Code for dynamic pivot:

```
DECLARE @Columns varchar(max)
SELECT @Columns =STUFF((
SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(NAME)
FROM
(select NAME
from sys.columns
where object_id=OBJECT_ID('[table_name]')
and (NAME LIKE '2%' or NAME LIKE '< 2%') L
FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')
```

I want to see an output where the dynamic pivot also selects the column with "<" in it. If I try the code without adding the condition "<" (or NAME LIKE '< 2%'), it works perfectly.

Would really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Are we missing something ehre? That SQL won't generate that error on it's own, from what i can see (can't test due to image for data), as you're probably quoting your values.

Comment: On a different note, why do you have a bunch of tables called `2004` to `2018`? This sounds like some (badly) denormalised data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DECLARE @Columns varchar(max)=''

SELECT @Columns += ','+QUOTENAME(NAME)
from sys.columns
where object_id=OBJECT_ID('[Table_Name]')and (NAME LIKE '2%' or NAME LIKE '< 2%')

SET  @Columns=STUFF(@Columns,1,1,'')

SELECT @Columns